# Identificando método mais eficaz de identificação do elemento central de uma matriz

Tags: python-2.7, matriz, numpy

Possuo o seguinte algoritmo:

```
import numpy as np

matriz = np.array(np.zeros(81).reshape(9, 9))

for i in range(1, matriz.shape[0], 3):
    for j in range(1, matriz.shape[1], 3):
        matriz[i, j] = 255

print(matriz)
```

Ele me gera a seguinte matriz:

```
[[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.  255.    0.    0.  255.    0.    0.  255.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.  255.    0.    0.  255.    0.    0.  255.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.  255.    0.    0.  255.    0.    0.  255.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]
```

Ou seja, essa algoritmo percorre essa matriz, com uma máscara 3x3, e inclui o valor 255 na sua posição central.

Estou trabalhando com processamento de imagens e essa operação tem se mostrado altamente custosa quando utilizo imagens grandes.

Alguém saberia me dizer se há outra forma de fazer isso, que proponho, de forma mais rápida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, em se tratando de algoritmo, não tem como fazer melhor. O motivo é simples: você tem que, no mínimo, preencher o valor 255  cada posição que vc quer. O que você faz no algoritmo é ir, um a um, preenchendo a matriz. Processamento de matriz realmente é pesado. Se você quiser melhorar o desempenho, pode procurar sobre como fazer o mesmo algoritmo de forma multi thread, para que seu processador possa paralelizar esse processamento e diminuir bastante o tempo de excução. Se sua cpu for 8 cores pode focar até 8 vezes mais rápido +-.

Comment: Obrigado @João Victor!
Vou pesquisar sobre multi thread.Acho que isso resolve meu problema.